# How to sort the array with a comparator?

Tags: java

I have an array that looks like this

```
ArrayList<footballClub> newClub = new ArrayList<footballClub>();
```

Football club is one of my java classes. I'm not sure how to sort it in one of my switch cases. My Array contains strings and ints and I need to put the contents in descending order. Such as the points of a football club. I don't want to post my whole code as I haven't compiled any errors and don't want others seeing it for reasons.

```
Collections.sort(ArrayList, new newClub);
```

This isn't right but I don't know how to go about this.

Comment: If you don't want to show your code, then we can't tell you how to improve or fix it. You'll have to find help with someone authorized to see your code, or read the dozens of questions and tutorials showing how to do what you want to do. Your code doesn't even compile, and you don't seem to understand how you invoke constructors yet, so I would start learning the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

In the Java conventions, classes are named LikeThis. So for the remainder of this answer, I will refer to your class as `FootballClub`.

First, you have to write a comparator class. The following snippet presumes you'll be putting the class inside another class. If it's going to be a top-level class, remove `static` from the first line.

```
static class DescendingByPointsComparator implements Comparator<FootballClub> {
    @Override
    public int compare(FootballClub lhs, FootballClub rhs) {
        return Integer.compare(rhs.getPoints(), lhs.getPoints());
    }
}
```

Here, I assumed that your `FootballClub` class has a `getPoints()` method, which returns an `int`, and that you're using Java 7 or newer.

Now, to use it:

```
Collections.sort(newClub, new DescendingByPointsComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with :

`Collections.sort(newClub , Collections.reverseOrder());`

Comment: That would assume that `FootballClub` implements `Comparable`. :-)